# Android WebView - Page loads only on old devices (4.1.2)

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, test-environments

I'm working on a Project, which loads a Webview within native Apps.

The App contains a WebView, which is only loading correctly on old Android Devices (4.1.2). On a new Version (4.4. and higher), the View stays blank.

I tried already to set the mixed content:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
}
```

But it wont change anything. Same with the handler.proceed() function.

```
 @Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```

The Website contains a lot of JavaScript, so i tried also different Settings like setDomStorageEnabled and so on... 
Actually the Environment is a test-server, so the Certificates are created on our own. So I just want to test the app and dont think about publishing and the probably issues. But I don't get an error in logcat, so I really don't know, what else could be wrong and how investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend you to debug your newer devices.

 Here you have a nice [sample](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews).
You will be able to debug all request and responses and even look through all of that fantastic JS stuff:)

Comment: thanks! technically the error occured because of a deprecated method (StringBufferInputStream). after use of the debugger i saw the message only on an emulator and changed it to the ByteArrayInputStream. Works now!

Comment: @a2hur Hm, it's not mentioned in your question. Can you attach that code, because honestly I didn't quite catch that statement about deprecated method.

Comment: Dont working code:
`InputStream stream = new StringBufferInputStream(message); //[...]`

Working code: 
`ByteArrayInputStream stream = null;
     try {
      stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(JsonFile.getBytes("UTF-8"));
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", stream);`
As i asked about the issue, i thoght that i handle the WebView correct and i need just some additionals for newer Android WebView. 
By using the chrome debugger, i received a NullPointer for my stream-variable.